# Trying to click() a button with no onclick event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to click Medium's clap button with `.click()`.

Here's what I've tried:

On [a medium post](https://medium.com/@satindersingh71/infinite-uicollectionview-b706c939ed3c), I run `let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('clapButton')[0];` to get the clap button, then run `btn.click();`.

After inspecting the button, it doesn't have an onclick event, so i'm not sure if i'm getting the wrong element, or if there's some other way to trigger it.

Is there some jquery code or something that's attaching the event to the button differently? Thanks!

### Edit

Sorry for missing details, i'm trying to run the code through a firefox extension. The code also doesn't work through firefox developer's console (I ran the code above). I'm not sure why it seems to work on Chrome just fine.

Comment: `btn.click()` will call the click event, it won't add an event handler to the button.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('clapButton')[0].click()` works fine in Chrome console

Comment: *it doesn't have an onclick event*  Yes, it is. But if you inspect the element in Chrome, for instance, you will see in the "event listener" tool window (refer: F12) some click event handlers attached to: document, parent div...

Comment: @adpro He wonders how the click event triggers without the element having an `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty vague, but I'll try to address it from as many angles as I can.

One: if you check the value of `btn.onclick` and get `null` or `undefined`, that doesn't necessarily mean the button doesn't have a click handler. There are two ways to add event listeners to elements:

```
btn.onclick = function() { ... };
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { ... });
```

In the latter case, the function won't be assigned to the `onclick` property of the element. `addEventListener` can actually be used to add multiple listeners to the same object, all of which will trigger when the event occurs.

Two: it's also possible that the button itself really doesn't have any click handlers at all. However, if any of its ancestors do, then those handlers will also be triggered when the button is clicked. This is called **event propagation** or **bubbling**, if you want to read up on it.

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the question. @gaetanoM gave the answer too, in his comment.

Comment: Would the event show up on firefox dev's tools as the ['ev' icon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners) If it was added with `addEventListener`? Thanks for the tip on bubbling too, I'll look into it

Comment: @GabDeJesus Unfortunately I do not use Firefox at all for development, so I can't help you there.

Comment: @GabDeJesus Yes, an event listener attached by `addEventListener` will show up on the element in Inspect tree on FF's dev tools.